# openssl decryption passphrase issue in perl

Tags: openssl

I am having difficulty analyzing how parameters are being treated when passed in a system call in perl.

When the following code runs . . . .

```
$password = ‘t5!rEDRkbYG@BJd!’;
system("pv myfile.aes | openssl enc -d -pass pass:$password -rc4 | md5sum > Decrypted.md5");
```

The code results in different hash values on different systems.

On the original system, which crashed, similar code ran and the file was encrypted and decrypted successfully.

When executing the code on another machine, the code runs but the clear text is invalid.
We think that the problem is with the special characters in the password.  We can fix the problem going forward but, need to know what actually got passed in the pass parameter to decrypt some data from the old system.

Thinking it has to do with how the shell is interpreting the password.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Mark, thanks for the response.

The code is running in Ubuntu 11.10 and bash is the shell.

I have tried to decrypt interactively and typed in the password when prompted so the exclamation marks should be passed in but I will try escaping the exclamation marks just in case.

It seems more like a double parsing issue.

I echoed the password and got the following.

```
echo t5!rEDRkbYG@BJd!
```

bash: !rEDRkbYG@BJd!: event not found

(I’m trying the above error text as a password just in case.)

In perl print “t5!rEDRkbYG@BJd!”; gives t5!rEDRkbYG!. Then bash must be parsing the passphrase again in the call to openssl.   If I echo t5!rEDRkbYG! . . .

```
echo t5!rEDRkbYG!
```

I get "bash: !rEDRkbYG!: event not found"

I’m running some password tests but in the meantime, does anyone have any ideas on how to see the result of all the parsing?

Mark, thanks again!

Comment: I would be suspicious of the exclamation mark.  Maybe try escaping them in the password:  `$password='t5\\!rED...';`  At the command line directly, I had to escape them.  Although I tried it from perl with a command similar to what you show, and it didn't matter.  But maybe it is shell dependent.  As an aside, you might add OS information and what shell you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark. I posted some additional information.

Comment: Did you try escaping the exclamation marks in the perl script?  The "event not found" is what I get when I type the command directly in a bash shell.